401 Unauthorized error after configuring NGINX for subdomains in MERN app (JWT cookie not set)
I deployed a MERN app using DigitalOcean, Nginx, and PM2. The app was working fine on the server’s IP, but after configuring NGINX for subdomains (api.example.com for the backend, example.com for the client), I started receiving 401 Unauthorized errors on API requests that undergo JWT verification. I think the cookie for the JWT (access_token_client) is not being set in the browser. Also, when I check Chrome Developer Tools > Application > Storage > Cookies > www.example.com, the access_token_client is not there.
First, I tried configuring the CORS in my server/index.js with credentials: true . I also allowed origins http://example.com, http://www.example.com, http://admin.example.com.
I also edited the sign in backend API controller since that is where the cookie is being set and the JWT is being signed to the user:
export const signin = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username })
    if (!user) return next(createError(404, "User not found!"))

    const isCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)  
    if (!isCorrect) return next(createError(400, "Wrong username or password!"))

    const token = jwt.sign({id: user._id}, process.env.JWT)
    const {password, ...others} = user._doc

    res.cookie("access_token_client", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false, // Set to false because I'm on HTTP not HTTPS
      sameSite: 'none', 
      domain: '.example.com', 
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 24 hours
    }).status(200)
      .json(others)

      console.log('Set-Cookie header:', res.getHeader('Set-Cookie'));
  } catch(err) {
    next(err)
  }
}

Then I edited the NGINX configuration of my server:
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name api.example.com;
    
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8800;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
      
 }
}

In my front end, specifically in Login.jsx, I also added withCredentials: true in the axios instance like this:
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL:process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL, // http://api.example.com/api
    withCredentials: true
  });

const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(loginStart());
    try {
      if (!username || !password) {
        throw new Error("Username and password are required");
      }
      const res = await axiosInstance.post("/auth/signin", {username, password});
      dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
      navigate('/dashboard');
    } catch(err) {
      dispatch(loginFailure());
      setError(err.response ? err.response.data.message : err.message);
    }
  }

and here's an example of an API that has a verifyToken middleware:
Controller:
export const getProgresses = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;

  if (userId !== req.user.id) {
    return next(createError(403, "Authorization error!"));
  }

  try {
    // Find all progress records for the current user
    const progresses = await Progress.find({ userId })
      .populate({
        path: 'unitId',
        select: 'title image', 
      })
      .populate({
        path: 'moduleId',
        select: 'title courseId', 
        populate: {
          path: 'courseId',
          select: 'title', 
        }
      })
      .sort({ updatedAt: -1 });

    // Map progresses to include courseTitle from moduleId.courseId
    const progressesWithCourseTitle = progresses.map(progress => ({
      ...progress.toObject(), 
      courseTitle: progress.moduleId.courseId.title 
    }));

    res.status(200).json(progressesWithCourseTitle);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};

Route:
router.get('/:userId', verifyToken, getProgresses)

Then here's my verifyToken.js middleware:
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import { createError } from './error.js'

export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  
  const token = req.cookies.access_token_client 
  
  if (!token) {
    console.log('No token found in cookies or headers');
    return next(createError(401, "You are not authenticated!"))
  }
  
  console.log('Token found:', token);
  
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT, (err, user) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log('Token verification failed:', err);
      return next(createError(403, "Invalid token!"))
    }
    console.log('Token verified successfully. User:', user);
    req.user = user
    next()
  })    
}

I was able to login/signin into my web application. Since I have this in my signin backend API console.log('Set-Cookie header:', res.getHeader('Set-Cookie')); I was able to see the token when I pm2 logs in my server. But whenever I make API requests that undergoes a middleware that verifies the token first, I get 401 unauthorized error. Upon checking, I think the reason why I'm getting this error is because it doesn't have a token to verify with in the first place. In the backend's verifyToken middleware, the cookie is not found (req.cookies is empty).
What could be causing the JWT cookie not to be set in the browser? Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Solved!
My frontend and backend are on different domains and modern browsers require the "secure" flag for cross-domain cookies. "Secure" flag can only be used if the domains (both frontend and backend) are served over HTTPS, not HTTP. So serving my domains in HTTPS ultimately solved my problem.
